# Using GetStream Method in Stream Object C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I have implemented a Tcp socket client successfully using:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(Endpoint);
tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 3000);
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

Now I am trying to make use the More general Socket class, but I cannot find a method that returns network stream like GetStream

```
Socket socketClient = new Socket(Endpoint);
socketClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 3000);
NetworkStream networkStream = socketClient.?????
```

Comment: Not all sockets *are* naturally streams though. If you know you'll always be using TCP (which *is* stream-based), why not use `TcpClient`? And if you might be using something else (e.g. UDP) how would you expect that to exhibit streamlike behaviour?

Comment: Yes you are right, but I wanted to make more general code so that in the future, I can change the protocol whenever I want 
I don't know till now either success or not as it is my first time to use Socket Class

Comment: But how do you expect to make general code that can deal with any socket if you're really requiring it to be a stream-based socket? It only *looks* like you're making the code more general, without *really* doing so, IMO.

Comment: I am sorry, I am just learning by doing, so really you are right, I am just beginning my socket programming, so I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NetworkStream` to get the `Stream`:

```
using(var stream = new NetworkStream(socketClient))
{
      //use the stream here
}
```

If you want to avoid `using` clause as you mentioned in comments then just don't use it and you can close the stream yourself, just like you said:

```
var stream = new NetworkStream(socketClient);
```

Comment: Using pattern will allow me to use stream inside it's scope
But how can I close the stream inside another method 

     private void CloseAll()
        {
            streamReader.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();
            stream.Close();           //cannot use stream object here 
        }

Comment: @suckerons: It's not clear what you're asking, but Ashkan has shown how to create a `NetworkStream` from a `Socket`, which is what you were asking about. Note that this will fail if the `Socket` if it's not a stream socket.

Comment: @suckerons well then simply don't use `using` and the you should close the stream yourself. look at edited answer